# Read a parameter in at a specific index in arraylist

Tags: java

I have a arraylist with 6 parameters, I wonder how to read one specific parameter with a getter from an other class.

I tried to use .indexOf of an .get from an instance of the arraylist. The variable in the other class is currentRoom = getKarta().get(roomNumber). roomNumber is set to 0 to represent the first room (the first index). What i am trying to do is to read the value from parameter n,s,ö and v with a switch. In the switch i have tried, and failed, to have the if read if n value is bigger than -1, assign that value to roomNumber.

Rum has parameters (String namn, String beskrivning, Integer n, Integer s,Integer ö, Integer v) and is in a separate class.

```
while(true){
System.out.print("" +currentRoom);
String sInput = input.nextLine();
switch (sInput)
 case "n"
 if(parameter3 >0) {
          rooms´Number = parameter3;

      }else {
         System.out.println("you cant go north)}
      break;
```

```
 public DragonTreasure() {
        karta = new ArrayList<Rum>();
               
        
So in the arraylist the values are for: namn, beskrivning, n,s,ö,v.      
        
        karta.add(new Rum("Entre", "Rummet är upplyst av några ljus som sitter på ett bord framför dig.",        1, 4, -1, -1));
        karta.add(new Rum("Död Kropp", "Du ser en död kropp på golvet.", -1, 0, 2, -1));
        karta.add(new Rum("Fackelrum", "Du ser en brinnande fackla i rummets ena hörn och känner en motbjudande stank.", -1, -1, 6, 1));
        karta.add(new Rum("Fuktigt Rum", "Du kommer in i ett fuktigt rum med vatten sipprandes längs den västra väggen.", 2, -1, 5, 4));
        karta.add(new Rum("Bergsrum", "Du kommer in i ett rymligt bergrum med en ljusstrimma sipprandes genom en spricka i den östra väggen.", 0, -1, 3, -1));
        karta.add(new Rum("Låst Rum", "Du har ingen nyckel som passar.", -1, -1, -1, 3));
        karta.add(new Rum("Utgång", "Du lämnar grottan med livet i behåll. Grattis, du förlorade inte!", -1, -1, -1, 2));
```

so for example in Rum at index zero i want to read 1 when asking for n value

Comment: Please post valid [mcve]s. These examples lack crucial information.

Comment: I am new to this, what else is needed? Have many classes and code...

Comment: Show us what you assigned to `input`.  Also show us the types of `n,s,ö and v`.

Comment: Fields within Rum class aren't numbered. Arraylist is irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

It's simple.
1st you need to add a getter in Rum class as follows.

```
public Integer getN() {
    return n;
}
```

Then in the caller class, you need to call that getter.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Rum> r = DragonTreasure();
    System.out.print(r.get(0).getN());
}
```

I'll add following complete solution for your convenience.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Rum> r = DragonTreasure();
        //GETTING THE VALUE OF N
        System.out.print(r.get(0).getN());
    }

    public static ArrayList<Rum> DragonTreasure() {
        ArrayList<Rum> karta = new ArrayList<>();

        karta.add(new Rum("ed", "Rd",1, 4, -1, -1));
        karta.add(new Rum("Dd", "Df", -1, 0, 2, -1));
        karta.add(new Rum("Fd", "Df", -1, -1, 6, 1));
        karta.add(new Rum("Fd", "Dd", 2, -1, 5, 4));
        karta.add(new Rum("Bd", "Dc", 0, -1, 3, -1));
        karta.add(new Rum("Ld", "Dx", -1, -1, -1, 3));
        karta.add(new Rum("Ud", "Ds", -1, -1, -1, 2));

        return karta;

    }

}

class Rum{
    public String namn;
    public String beskrivning;
    public Integer n;
    public Integer s;
    public Integer o;
    public Integer v;

    public Rum(String namn, String beskrivning, Integer n, Integer s, Integer o, Integer v) {
        this.namn = namn;
        this.beskrivning = beskrivning;
        this.n = n;
        this.s = s;
        this.o = o;
        this.v = v;
    }

    public Integer getN() {
        return n;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a class that has a reference to the `List` and you want to get elements from the `List` using a 1-based index rather than the 0-based index that a `List` employs.  A simple solution is to write a method that does the offset for you.

```
public Rum getRoom(int roomNumber) {
  return karta.get(roomNumber - 1);
}
```

**Consider using a `Map` keyed on a room ID instead of a `List`.**